# Removing the navigation menu from the node menu settings in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, menu

How do you remove the "Navigation" menu (and others) from the menu settings on the node edit form? I suspect this can be achieved somehow using a hook like module_form_alter, but am not sure how to implement it. The motivation for this is to remove the confusion our users have when menus other than the standard primary links menu is in the drop down. The aim is to restrict the options to just the menus they will need/want to post content to.

This question is in part related to [an earlier question I asked in regards to Domain Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036293/hide-other-domains-menus-from-node-edit-form-on-a-drupal-site-using-domain-acces) that I have not yet been able to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two modules that maybe do what you want, I never tried them myself tough. [Menu per Role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) and [Menu Settings per Content Type](http://drupal.org/project/ctm).

Comment: He's not talking about the menu block, but the menu options in the form itself.

Comment: Yes, it's the menu options for assigning a node to a menu that I am trying to alter; not the menus themselves.

Comment: Menu Settings per Content Type works like a dream, thanks. Just need to now work out how to get it to be domain aware, but this has set me on the right course.